# Does Mogenerator works with Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode6, mogenerator

I've setup Mogenerator for my project using [tutorial](http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/) but is some reason it doesn't generate files on Build.

**Here is my script:**
[image]

**My Project Folder:**
[image]
**And *.xcdatamodel file:**
[image]

I'm choosing Mogenerator target, pressing build. Build succeeded, but no files created. I know that mogenerator doesn't add it to my xcode project and lookup for files in project folder in finder, but nothing new there :(.
I just don't understand what am I doing wrong. Tried a lot of scripts variants.

I'll be grateful for any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is my script. It works fine. Replace content inside <> with yours.
Also check the path to shell.
Mine is `/bin/sh` .

https://gist.github.com/madnik/8a91d546cc7031f829c5

```
MODEL_PATH="$PROJECT_DIR/<RootDirectory>/<ModelName>.xcdatamodeld"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="$PROJECT_DIR/<RootDirectory>/Classes/Model"
mogenerator --v2 --model $MODEL_PATH --output-dir $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
```

Note I'm using latest version of mogenerator. --v2 argument is basically semantic versioning for tool arguments.

Comment: thanks for advice with path to Shell. I was providing wrong one in my script

Comment: enjoy moderator. Any users installed mogenerator using zsh instead of default shell. Make sure path should be 'bin/zsh' . Zsh is much popular among web dev specially rails. I hv seen few users have trouble with this. This comment might be helpful for someone using zsh.

Comment: The new --v2 argument is basically semantic versioning for tool arguments.  It might be confusing to mention is as mogenerator v2. I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in script. I don't know why but I had to explicitly provide path to mogenerator (which is "/usr/local/bin/mogenerator"):

```
/usr/local/bin/mogenerator --v2 --model MogeneratorProject/MogeneratorProject.xcdatamodeld --output-dir MogeneratorProject/Model
```

Also I've been providing wrong path to Shell. Now it's `/bin/sh`